# C# prohibit upcast

Tags: c#

Is there a way to prohibit implicit upcast of a paticular  class ?

I want the compiler to throw an error if a function accepting MyBase is passed an instance of MyDerived (same for assignment etc)

My use case is trying immitate c++ typedef by inheriting but upcasting break this.

Comment: No, you cannot. A `MyDerived` **is** a `MyBase`, by definition.

Comment: Pretty unclear how you got into this horrible pickle, do stop trying to imitate C++.  The result is doomed to turn into C--.  The C# language supports type aliases with the *using* statement.

Comment: using using is lame and only works in file scope

Answer (score 3):

No. You can't do that on compile time. It is a derived class after all. It it its purpose to do so. You can on run time, but I don't think you want that.

You can make `MyBase` sealed if you don't want any derived type to exist.

I do wonder why you would want this, but that is a whole different question...

Comment: the reason is in the question

Comment: If your reason is "My use case...", then explain that in more detail. It is absolute unclear why you'd want this.